# Selected record in laravel edit form not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing one application in Laravel framework.

I am trying to select an option in select box in edit screen. selected word is appending in the option, but the select box still not showing the selected value on page load.

Here is the code snippet for the same:

```
<select id="language" name="language" value="en" class="fullwidth mdl-selectfield__select">
      <option value="de" {{($user->language == "de") ? 'selected' : ''}}>Deutsch</option>
      <option value="en" {{($user->language == "en") ? 'selected' : ''}}>English</option>
      <option value="fr" {{($user->language == "fr") ? 'selected' : ''}}>Français</option>
      <option value="nl" {{($user->language == "nl") ? 'selected' : ''}}>Nederlands</option>
</select>
```

Here value of $user->language is 'fr'.

Please let me know what is wrong in this code.

Thank you.

Regards,
Saloni

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take here, either outputting it from within the curly braces (Slight amendment required to correct your code), or using the blade @if directive. Examples of both have been included below:

Amended version of your code (selected="selected"):

```
<select id="language" name="language" value="{{ $user->language }}" class="fullwidth mdl-selectfield__select">
  <option value="de" {{($user->language == "de") ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>Deutsch</option>
  <option value="en" {{($user->language == "en") ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>English</option>
  <option value="fr" {{($user->language == "fr") ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>Français</option>
  <option value="nl" {{($user->language == "nl") ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}>Nederlands</option>
```

Blade @if directive:

```
<select id="language" name="language" value="{{ $user->language }}" class="fullwidth mdl-selectfield__select">
  <option value="de" @if($user->language == "de") selected @endif>Deutsch</option>
  <option value="en" @if($user->language == "en") selected @endif>English</option>
  <option value="fr" @if($user->language == "fr") selected @endif>Français</option>
  <option value="nl" @if($user->language == "nl") selected @endif>Nederlands</option>
```

Comment: the issue is with the value="en" in the select which need to remove to see actual selection